# MySql setting like names to NULL

Tags: mysql

I am not really sure how to ask this question, but here goes.

If I have a query such as this:

```
SELECT `locations`.`location_name` AS 'Location', `inventory`.`equip_model` AS 'Model', count( `inventory`.`equip_model` ) AS 'Count'
FROM mod_inventory_data AS `inventory`
LEFT JOIN mod_locations_data AS `locations` ON `locations`.location_id = `inventory`.location_id
WHERE inventory.equip_model LIKE '%iPad%'
GROUP BY Location, Model
```

which returns a result such as this:

```
Location        Model                    Count
------------------------------------------------
Bannach         iPad                     7
Bannach         iPad 2                   1
Ben Franklin    iPad                     3
Ben Franklin    iPad 2                   1
Ben Franklin    iPad 64 gb               3
Ben Franklin    iPad2 64GB               1
Jefferson       iPad                     4
Jefferson       Ipad 216 gb wi-fi        6
Jefferson       iPad2 64GB               2
Kennedy         iPad                     2
Kennedy         iPad 2 WIFI 16GB Black   1
Madison         iPad                     3
Madison         iPad 2                   6
McKinley        iPad                     4
McKinley        iPad 2                   2
McKinley        iPad 2 MC769LL/A         6
McKinley        iPad 64 gb               1
```

Is there a way to replace the duplicate location names so it looks like this:

```
Location        Model                    Count
------------------------------------------------
Bannach         iPad                     7
NULL            iPad 2                   1
Ben Franklin    iPad                     3
NULL            iPad 2                   1
NULL            iPad 64 gb               3
NULL            iPad2 64GB               1
Jefferson       iPad                     4
NULL            Ipad 216 gb wi-fi        6
NULL            iPad2 64GB               2
Kennedy         iPad                     2
NULL            iPad 2 WIFI 16GB Black   1
Madison         iPad                     3
NULL            iPad 2                   6
McKinley        iPad                     4
NULL            iPad 2                   2
NULL            iPad 2 MC769LL/A         6
NULL            iPad 64 gb               1
```

Basically I want the location name to only show on the first instance found implying that any null after that is for that location.

Hope I asked that right...

Comment: Just a comment on the data structure you are returning. I do not think the data you are wanting to return is a proper constructed data. The client end should be doing the parsing instead of writing a query that will return such a dataset.

Comment: This is the type of operation you usually want to do at the application level.

Comment: I can do it at the application level, I was just wondering if there was a way to do it from in MySql.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Location, Model, Count
FROM (
    SELECT IF(Location = @PrevLocation, NULL, Location) AS Location,
           Model, Count, @PrevLocation := Location
    FROM (<your query>) AS subq
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @PrevLocation := NULL) AS init
    ) AS subq2
```

Comment: I just tried this, and it worked perfectly.  Thanks.